# Convert UNPIVOT from SQL Server to Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, database-migration

I have a script from SQL Server, that I need to convert to Redshift

Here is part of script, that I have trouble with

```
    UNPIVOT
(
SeatCharge
FOR Description IN (
        PM_Core,
        PM_RCM,
        PM_Advanced_RCM,
        PM_Payroll,
        PM_DXM,
        PM_Messaging,
        PM_Tasks,
        Clinical_Core,
        Clinical_Data_Collection,
        Clinical_Auditing_Tools,
        Clinical_Group_Sessions,
        Clinical_ABC_Data,
        Clinical_AGA,
        LMS_Core,
        HRIS_PTO,
        LMS_Course_Groups,
        PM_Reach_Me,
        PM_Redshift,
        HRIS_Benefits,
        HRIS_Assets)
)u
```

How I can correctly convert it to redshift?

Comment: Why you minusing?

Comment: you have to write it by using case when

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `union all` to make `UNPIVOT` in *amazon-redshift*

```
SELECT  PM_Core SeatCharge
FROM yourTable
union all
SELECT PM_RCM 
FROM yourTable
union all
SELECT PM_Advanced_RCM 
FROM yourTable
union all 
SELECT PM_Payroll 
FROM yourTable
union all 
SELECT PM_DXM 
FROM yourTable
....
```

**NOTE**

when you are doing `UNPIVOT` need to make sure `UNPIVOT` columns data type are the same.